# Why I am getting null result from a sql query even though the condition is true?

Tags: c#, sql

I have a table named ***'generation_unit_mobile'***:
[image]

Now I am trying to get result based on the following where clause:

```
public int MobileExistToAnotherGenerationUnit(string mobileNo, long generationUnitId)
{
    var result = _mobileRepository.Table
        .Where(gum => gum.mobileno == mobileNo && gum.generation_unit_id != generationUnitId)
        .Select(s => new Generation_unit_mobile
        {
            id = s.id
        })
       .FirstOrDefault();

    return result == null ? 0 : 1;
}
```

From this above piece of code MobileExistToAnotherGenerationUnit should return **1** for generation_unit_id = 2 and mobileno=01673050495. But for this mobileno and generation_unit_id = 2 it returns 0. And strange is it also returns 0 for generation_unit_id = 1 and mobileno = 01673050495. whats wrong with my code?

Comment: what is the data type of mobileno column/

Comment: Why you don't return `bool`? Every `Exists` method should retun `bool` not `int`. Convert to `int` where you need that.

Comment: gum.generation_unit_id != generationUnitId might be the problem.. write : gum.generation_unit_id == generationUnitId

Comment: Why don't you use `_mobileRepository.Any(...)` ?

Comment: is s.id returning 14?

Comment: Use the debugger and tell us the record that is returned. Instead of `FirstOrDefault` you could also use `ToList` to see all matching records in case there are multiple.

Comment: Is Entity Framework in use?

Comment: @Zaynul Abadin Tuhin: mobileno  is string type.

Comment: @Fildor: YES. I am using Entity Framework.

Answer (score 0):

Convert mobileno as a string  so that
  Db get below query

```
         Select * from your_table where 
          generation_unit_id=2 and 
          Mobileno='01673040595'  --single quote essential
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the Count of the Result:

**If Count Is Zero Return 0 Else 1**

```
public int MobileExistToAnotherGenerationUnit(string mobileNo, long generationUnitId)
{
    int result = _mobileRepository.Table
    .Where(gum => gum.mobileno == mobileNo && gum.generation_unit_id != 
     generationUnitId)
    .Select(s => new Generation_unit_mobile
    {
        id = s.id
    }).ToList().Count;

    return result == 0 ? 0 : 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer will not solve your missing results, it's just a hint how you could simplify your code.

```
public Task<bool> MobileExistToAnotherGenerationUnit(string mobileNo, long generationUnitId) =>
    _mobileRepository.Table
      .AnyAsync(gum => gum.mobileno == mobileNo && gum.generation_unit_id != generationUnitId);
```

It seems that:

- you never use the returned records (if any), so Any() seems to be better
- you're doing a network operation, doing it async makes your system more scalable